# jQuery remove multiple last items on .each iteration

Tags: javascript, jquery, each

I am having trouble removing the last DD and DT tags from a definition list when prepending new content using .each. My goal is to remove a set of DD and DT tags with each iteration (as new DD and DT tags are prepended). The following is example code I am using:

```
shouts_list = $("#shouts dl#shouts_list");
$.each(json.shouts, function (id, shout) {
            $("<dt>" + shout.name + "</dt><dd>" + shout.message +  "</dd>").hide().prependTo(shouts_list).slideDown('slow', 'swing', function() {
            $("#shouts_list > dt:last, #shouts_list > dd:last").slideUp('slow', 'swing');
            }).fadeIn();
        });
```

Each time my json object contains multiple items, only one set of DT and DD are removed from the end.

I am learning jQuery and JavaScript slowly and have been stuck on this issue for a while. What would be a good way to remove items from the end of the list for each iteration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only one element is being removed from the list because the `each` loop is going through all the items in `json.shouts` before the first `slideUp` call finishes (ie the loop is too fast or slideUp is too slow). This means that each time this executes:

```
$("#shouts_list > dt:last, #shouts_list > dd:last").slideUp('slow', 'swing');
```

the original last item in the list is always being found, so you're actually calling `slideUp` on the same element `json.shouts.length` number of times. You need to get all the original items in the list before the each loop starts and count backwards to remove one for each new item added.

This should do the trick:

```
shouts_list = $("#shouts dl#shouts_list");
var existingDts = shouts_list.find("> dt");
var existingDds = shouts_list.find("> dd");

$.each(json.shouts, function (id, shout) {
     $("<dt>" + shout.name + "</dt><dd>" + shout.message +  "</dd>")
       .hide().prependTo(shouts_list)
       .slideDown('slow', 'swing', function() {
           $(existingDts[existingDts.length - 1 - id]).slideUp('slow', 'swing');
           $(existingDds[existingDds.length - 1 - id]).slideUp('slow', 'swing');
     })
    .fadeIn();
});
```

Comment: Thanks! This works. The animation looks a little strange. But I understand the concept now. I'm just a little confused on what this syntax actually means: "existingDts.length - 1 - id"

Comment: `existingDts.length` minus one minus `id`. This is done to get the index of the item in the array (`existingDts` and `existingDds`) that you wish to remove. `length - 1` gets you the index of the last item in an array. `id` will be 0, 1, 2, 3... going through the each loop

Comment: Ah, I understand now. I used console.log() to show me information through the iteration to help me understand. Thanks again!